# What determines the Hamiltonian of an isolated quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Let an isolated quantum system be in state $|\psi\rangle$. Then, quantum mechanics says the system evolves in time according to some Hamiltonian $H$, which *does not* depend on $|\psi\rangle$. But the first postulate of quantum mechanics also says that $|\psi\rangle$ *completely* describes the isolated system. If so, how can $H$ not depend on it? What then determines $H$ of an *isolated* system? (Take the universe as an example, that's isolated in the ideal sense, as there is nothing outside it. Still, its Hamiltonian depends on something other than its own state?)

Comment: What I will say is probably a little bit approximate but in short I would say that the Hamiltonian actually define the system, and the quantum state define in which state your system is.

Comment: What confuses me is that I'd naively think that $H$ is part of the system's *description*, so it's surprising $H$ does not depend on the state vector which supposedly completely describes the system.

Comment: You are familiar with $\mathbf{H}\psi=E\psi$, right?

Comment: Yes, I saw this, but how would it help me here?

Comment: @TamásV Consider classical mechanics. Your system state is entirely defined by the values of position, momentum $(q,p)$ because as soon as you know those values at an instant of time $t_0$ you can deduce its state for all further time from Newton's equation of motion. But you need in addition to know what to put in those equations of motion (which force are acting on the system: gravity ? electromagnetic forces ?). Those force are the analog role of the Hamiltonian. And $(q,p)$ is your $|\psi\rangle$

Comment: Take the simplest of quantum systems: the particle in a 1D box: its Hamiltonian is $\mathbf{H}=-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m} \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}$. Now solve $\mathbf{H}\psi=E\psi$ and you get the states $\psi_n(x)$. So the Hamiltonian **determines** what states (eigenstates) you get.

Comment: @StarBucK Ok, I see, but e.g. $F=ma$ is true for *any* system, but here it seems, by analogy, as if this law would take the form something like $F=\alpha ma$, where the factor $\alpha$ depends on the concrete system in question, with different isolated systems having different $\alpha$ values.

Comment: @TamásV No - the analogy is that $F$ depends on the concrete system in question, with different systems being subject to different forces.

Comment: @J. Murray My point is that in $F=ma$, $m$ depends on the system at hand, it's part of the system's description. In the Schrödinger equation, $H$ also depends on the system at hand (e.g. the universe), but it's apparently *not* part of the systems description, as $|\psi\rangle$ completely describes the system, and we cannot deduce $H$ from $|\psi\rangle$. But ok, basically, reading all the responses, I can say what is written in the link I read and in many other books is just plain wrong, or misleading at best: https://quantum.country/qm

Comment: @TamásV You're simply interpreting "$|\psi\rangle$ completely describes the system" in a way the authors of your references do not intend.  What they mean is that if you know $|\psi\rangle$, you know all of the information about the current state of the system, i.e. you can calculate the probabilities of the outcomes of every experiment you could possibly perform on your system. $|\psi\rangle$ does **not** describe the *dynamics* of the system - how the state and those associated probabilities will change with time.  By analogy, the position and momentum of every particle in a classical [...]

Comment: [...] system define its dynamical state, but they do **not** tell you how that state will change as time goes on.  For that, you need to know what forces/potentials the particles are subject to, what their respective masses are, etc.

Comment: @J. Murray Yes, I did exactly that, took the expression *completely describes* at face value. What I can't imagine is this: how can it be that if I change the state of an isolated system (e.g. I flip a qubit secretly), its Hamiltonian remains the same? As I don't see why it is the *same* system after the change of the state. Ok, but that's my private problem it seems, others find it obvious :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119747/discussion-between-j-murray-and-tamas-v).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the first postulate of quantum mechanics also says that |ψ⟩ completely describes the isolated system.

$|\psi\rangle$ completely describes the **state** of an isolated system at that moment in time.  It does not describe how that state evolves with time.

> What then determines H of an isolated system?

One could ask the same about a classical system as well.  Different Hamiltonians describe different physical systems.  If you have a particular system in mind, which Hamiltonian you should use to model it is not always a trivial question to answer.

When describing particles interacting with some potential, you will typically encounter so-called *Schrodinger* Hamiltonians of the form

$$\hat H = \frac{1}{2m} \hat P^2 + V(\hat X)$$
with $\hat P$ and $\hat X$ the position and momentum operators defined on whichever Hilbert space is appropriate (usually $L^2(\mathbb R)$ for a 1D system or $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$ for a 3D system).

On the other hand, sometimes your system is best modeled as a system of interacting spins with fixed spatial locations as in [the Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model), which involves a different Hilbert space and a different kind of Hamiltonian.  Sometimes your system can be reasonably well-modeled as a simple two-state system subjected to an external potential, as in the [ammonia maser](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_09.html) toy model.

At the end of the day, constructing a mathematical model for a quantum system involves choosing a Hilbert space (which defines the set of states the system can occupy) and a Hamiltonian operator (which defines how those states evolve with time).  In real applications, both tasks are generally non-trivial; the standard recipe is to make those choices based on physical intuition and experience, check the predictions of the resulting model against experiment, and then update your choices if those predictions aren't sufficiently accurate for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that the Hilbert-space vector $\vert \psi\rangle$ describes is, as the name suggests, the *state* of the system at a particular point in time. More precisely, $\vert \psi\rangle$ tells you about the statistics of any observable you'd want to measure *at that point in time*.

This has nothing to do with describing how the state of the system (i.e. $\vert \psi\rangle$) changes in time. That is described by the Hamiltonian, which is completely independent of the state of the system at some point in time.

To give you an example, let's say I have a spin $1/2$ particle in the $\left\vert\uparrow\right\rangle$ state. As an experimenter, I can obviously start tweaking my control instruments in order to manipulate the state of the system independently of the system's initial state. In fact, I might not even know what the state of the system  is to begin with! In this case, I'm changing the Hamiltonian of the system completely independently of what its initial state is.